# How do I get rosjava development environment setup?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running through the rosjava Getting Started, but I am having trouble with the environment setup. When I try a gradle build.gradle on the example file, I get:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/pjmartin/my_workspace/ycpjava/build.gradle' line: 16
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ycpjava'.
  Cause: Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_7srnsdir7dj4a7drkst1r6jo3l$_run_closure1_closure3@4f980c26] on root project 'ycpjava'.

Why would there be a Maven error? I am new to both the Gradle process and rosjava. Any guidance would be helpful!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36348/how-do-i-get-rosjava-development-environment-setup?/) by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-06-14**:
Please post the contents of your build.gradle script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can ignore this post. I have figured out gradle a bit more and moved beyond this problem. However, I am having issues getting a fresh project running. I am posting a new question soon.

---

Originally posted by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) with karma: 40 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0